# How to set owner of existing SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, smo

I'm trying to set a SQL Server database owner using C# and SMO. If the database does not exist, I can assign its owner. But if I want to set the owner of an existing database, I get an error.

Working code for new database:

```
Server server = new Server("WINSERVER\\SQLEXPR");
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
Database database = new Database(server, "MyDatabase");
db.Create();

database.SetOwner("SOMEOWNER", true)
database.Refresh();
```

Not working code for an existing database:

```
Server server = new Server("WINSERVER\\SQLEXPR");
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
Database database = new Database(server, "MyDatabase");

database.SetOwner("SOMEOWNER", true)
database.Refresh();
```

Error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.InvalidSmoOperationException: You cannot execute this operation since the object has not benn created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Server server = new Server("WINSERVER\\SQLEXPR");
server.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;

// changed line below
Database database = server.Databases["MyDatabase"];

database.SetOwner("SOMEOWNER", true)
database.Refresh();
```

No need to create a new `Database` object, just pull it from the database collection on the server already.